# (C++) Accessing first character of first element in first column of vector pair

Tags: c++, vector

I am attempting to compare the first character of the first element of the first column of a vector pair to a user input `int` and only keep those values that start with that number. The pair is formatted as

```
vector< pair <int, string> > vec;
```

I've tried

```
for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
{
    if(&vec.first[0] != userInput)
    {
        vec.erase(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    }
}
```

which throws the error

```
error: 'class std::vector<std::pair<int, std::basic_string<char> > >' has no member named 'first'
```

If anyone has a way to do this (seemingly simple) task, I would be hugely grateful - many an hour has been spent searching for the solution, but to no avail.

Comment: It would be `vec[0].first`.

Comment: `vec` is a vector of pairs, not a "vector pair". So "the first character of the first element of the first column of a vector pair" doesn't make any sense. Can you explain in more detail what you want to achieve ?

Comment: So the vector has information stored as
`10515 This is a string\\
20515 This is also a string`
And I want to be able to input, say, 2 and only have the second string displayed.

Comment: As a sidenote, you can replace the erase wtih `vec.clear();`

Comment: @DaveScott : to access the second string, you want `vec[1].second` - `vec[1]` gets the second pair from the vector, and the `.second` bit gets the string from that pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
&vec.first[0]
```

To:

```
vec.front().first
```

And as stated by Cyber in the comments, `vec[0].first` is also valid.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the position of the verctor first, and then the first element of the pair:

```
vec[0].first
```

Answer (score 0):

The first method allows you to easily access the first item in a pair. When applied to a pair variable, first will give you the first item (the int in your case) and second will give you the second item (the string in your case).

You are mistakenly applying the method called 'first' to the vector and not to one of the pairs in the vector.

To access one of the pairs in the vector use:

```
vec[i].first
```

where you are accessing the ith element in the vector (sticking with your example where you are using i to denote the loop counter). vec[i] returns a variable of type pair, which you can then call the first method on.

The error you get

```
error: 'class std::vector<std::pair<int, std::basic_string<char> > >' has no member named 'first'
```

tries to explain this, C++ are always quite hard to read. It tells you that there is no member (in this case a method) named 'first' that can be found to be applied to a variable of type vector of pairs of ints mapped to strings.